# R files have no content

Tags: r, debugging

Has anyone run into an issue in R (R-4.2.0) where only some saved files now have no content? I think it happened after I copy-pasted a folder of files to a new location (USB to Desktop). I've tried using the recover projects function `rsrecovr::recovr()`, but this didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you saving files in a DropBox or OneDrive folder? What OS? And what RStudio version?

Comment: I've been going back and forth (working from home to office), saving them to my external hard drive (WD 1TB "My Passport Ultra" Portable HD) and my work computer. Working on a PC, Windows 10, 2022.02.3 version of RStudio.

Comment: Maybe the hard drive was disconnected before being unmounted? Or the file transfer wasn't complete before you unplugged it? The files show a size of 0KB so they are empty. The code is gone unless you explicitly have backups running on these files.